# Implementing a warning system before account locks

Tags: discussion, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can you know that you are quite close to losing your account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86603/how-can-you-know-that-you-are-quite-close-to-losing-your-account)

There have been a lot of discussion the last couple of days on what to do with [bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system)/[excessive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86165/should-we-require-minimum-reputation-to-continue-asking-questions) askers and how to prevent them to continue adding noise to the system. Those posts have also been followed by others dealing with the issue of recovery ([after some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86313/can-bad-question-askers-be-forgiven), or [after some service back to the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86307/allow-marginal-question-askers-to-regain-their-question-asking-privileges-by-perf)). Also, I've seen many users asking why they are banned from making questions (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86594/getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-after-20) and [this other one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86626/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)) with an [IP lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error).

What I have not seen anywhere is a system to allow the users to improve the behavior **before** the lock is in place. One or two warnings (either by email, or better yet by a popup after login and while they're writing questions) could save many of those individuals from SE doom. It would give them the chance to learn that what they're doing is not welcomed here. I understand that downvotes and question closings *should be enough warning*, but obviously it isn't for many.

AS I said in other posts, I do not have a position taken on whether the askers should be limited, but I do believe that no action should be taken before a fair warning.

What do you think? Should this be implemented? Or downvotes should be all the warning they get?

Comment: dup or similar with this [how can you know that you are quite close to losing your account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86603/how-can-you-know-that-you-are-quite-close-to-losing-your-account)

Comment: @YOU somehow I missed it in my search. Edit: It's even asked 3 hours ago, on the front page :/ I wrote this as a continuation of this reply yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86313/can-bad-question-askers-be-forgiven/86325#86325

Comment: I didn't vote to close it, yours is more like a feature-request, the other seems like faq to me. And I agree with you that, I think we should inform users and let them fix instead of kicking out.

Comment: @YOU: I agree, but even now affected users can fix things once they learn. The lock out only affect asking new questions, they can edit their less than optimal material, answer questions, and so on to get out of the dog house.